Factoring Laurent polynomial - how to distribute powers in denominator to get polynomial Laurent factors
Not sure how to do this with Factor/Collect etc. I'm thinking this might not be straightforward at all.
Given a large Laurent polynomial I am trying to factor it into irreducible Laurent polynomials.
NOTE: The large polynomial in question will be symmetric in the positive and negative exponents. i.e
x^-n + x^-n+1 ... + 1 + ... x^n-1 + x^n
Example:
bigpoly = 1 + 1/x^40 + 1/x^39 + 1/x^38 + 1/x^37 + 1/x^36 + 1/x^35 + 1/x^34 + \
1/x^33 + 1/x^32 + 1/x^31 + 1/x^30 + 1/x^29 + 1/x^28 + 1/x^27 + 1/x^26 \
+ 1/x^25 + 1/x^24 + 1/x^23 + 1/x^22 + 1/x^21 + 1/x^20 + 1/x^19 + \
1/x^18 + 1/x^17 + 1/x^16 + 1/x^15 + 1/x^14 + 1/x^13 + 1/x^12 + 1/x^11 \
+ 1/x^10 + 1/x^9 + 1/x^8 + 1/x^7 + 1/x^6 + 1/x^5 + 1/x^4 + 1/x^3 + \
1/x^2 + 1/x + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8 + x^9 + \
x^10 + x^11 + x^12 + x^13 + x^14 + x^15 + x^16 + x^17 + x^18 + x^19 + \
x^20 + x^21 + x^22 + x^23 + x^24 + x^25 + x^26 + x^27 + x^28 + x^29 + \
x^30 + x^31 + x^32 + x^33 + x^34 + x^35 + x^36 + x^37 + x^38 + x^39 + \
x^40;

Factor[bigpoly]

(* ((1 + x + x^2) (1 + x^3 + x^6) (1 + x^9 + x^18) (1 + x^27 + 
   x^54))/x^40 *)



What I would like is a way to distribute the denominator x^40 to the 4 individual factors so that I get:
((x^-1 + 1 + x) (x^-3 + 1 + x^3) (x^-9 + 1 + x^9) (x^-27 + 1 + 
   x^27))

Now I can write some messy code to do this but is there a quick way to handle this job using some inbuilt command or two such as Factor/Collect etc.
If there is I haven't found it. As always any help/insight would be appreciated.
EDIT: The more I think about it this is a bad question. It's basically asking Mathematica to mind read. I can see that dividing the factors in brackets by the Median of the exponents of the given factor does the job.
I think it probably should be closed!!!!

Is this well defined in general? What are the criteria for distributing to each factor?

@DanielLichtblau That the factors are symmetric in the sense that you get a form like x^-n + x^-n+1 ... + 1 + ... x^n-1 + x^n. Obviously the example I showed they were just 3 terms in each factor - in practice they could be far larger.

With[{t = List @@ (bigpoly // Factor)}, Times @@ Expand[(x^Flatten[{Total[#], -#} &@Exponent[Rest[t][[All, 2]], x]]) t]]

How would this work in practice with this example? `In[151]:=
smallpoly = 1 + 1/x^5 + 1/x^4 + 1/x^3 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^9;
Factor[smallpoly]
Out[152]= (1 + x + x^2 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8 + x^9 + x^14)/x^5`

@DanielLichtblau It wouldn't  - if you notice the input polynomial has to be symmetric in the sense I asked for the factors to be. As I have said in the edit - it's a bad question really. Also I solved it with a one liner. Just divide each polynomial by the Median of it's exponents.

Symmetry didn't seem to be in the statement of the problem. For that restriction, your proposed method seems fine.

@DanielLichtblau I should have worded the initial statement better - and after a few minutes thinking about it the answer was obvious. I can't close the question myself from what I can see - but it probably should be closed.

Nobody has voted to close it so maybe it's useful. In case it remains open, I'd add symmetry to the explicit  requirements e.g. f[x]==f[1/x] so it becomes a more viable question for possible future reference.


EDIT: ...  dividing the factors in brackets by the Median of the exponents
Yes, except when it is odd. See my answer below.


@DanielLichtblau  How would you factorize, e.g. 4 + 2/x^2 + 5/x + 5 x + 2 x^2 then?
Question makes sense when exponents of some usual factors are odd.

You can use
FactorSymmetricLaurent[poly_, x_] := 
 Module[{fpoly}, 
  fpoly = Times @@ (If[EvenQ[Exponent[#1, x]], 
        Expand[#1/x^(Exponent[#1, x]/2)]^#2, 
        Expand[#1*(#1 /. x -> 1/x)]^(#2/2)] & @@@ FactorList[poly]);
   Together[poly/fpoly] fpoly]

Then you have
FactorSymmetricLaurent[bigpoly, x]
(*==>(1 + 1/x + x) (1 + 1/x^3 + x^3) (1 + 1/x^9 + x^9) (1 + 1/x^27 + x^27)*)

This odd-looking If[EvenQ[Exponent[#1, x]],...] is needed to correctly handle cases like
FactorSymmetricLaurent[4 + 2/x^2 + 5/x + 5 x + 2 x^2, x]
(*==> (1/x + x) (5 + 2/x + 2 x)*)

Is it what you asked for?

You can try this substitution:
f = Factor[bigpoly] // Numerator
# /. {Plus[1,Power[x,a_],Power[x,b_]]/;b==2*a->Plus[1,Power[x,-a],Power[x,a]],1+x+x^2->1+1/x+x}& /@ f


How about this? (Using the same idea as @yarchik's)
Clear["Global`*"]; 

reciprocalPolyRewrite[f_, var_ : x] := Module[{e, w},
  w = CoefficientList[f, var];
  If[w === Reverse[w],
   e = Exponent[f, var]/2;
   Expand[f/x^e]*x^e, f]
  ];

Factor[bigpoly] /. {f_?(PolynomialQ[#, x]&) :> reciprocalPolyRewrite[f]}


